# How do I modify the install name of a .dylib at build time

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, autoconf, install-name-tool

I am building the [google-gflags](http://code.google.com/p/google-gflags/) commandline flags library for C++ on Mac OS X (10.7.1). The build process is as such:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=output
$ make
$ make install
```

I'd like to change the install name of the generated shared library at build time and not use `install_name_tool` afterwards.

By default, the [install name](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html) of the generated shared library, `libgflags.dylib`, is the output path:

```
$ otool -L ./output/libgflags.dylib
$ ./output/libgflags.dylib:
    /tmp/gflags-1.5/output/lib/libgflags.0.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.0.0)
```

The man page for `ld(1)` has a `-install_name` option which can be used to change the install name of a dynamic library at link-time.

For example, with a dummy program:

```
$ g++ -dynamiclib temp.cc -install_name /tmp/temp.dylib -o temp.dylib
$ otool -L temp.dylib 
temp.dylib:
    /tmp/temp.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.0.0)
```

But, I am unable to use this command line option with the `./configure` script. I've tried manually setting the `CFLAGS` variable, but that results in a error:

```
$ CFLAGS="-install_name /tmp/desired/location/libgflags.dylib" ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /opt/local/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/vibhav/Code/install_name_test/gflags-1.5':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

So, is it possible for me to change the install name of .dylib generated by `configure` and `make` without using `install_name_tool`?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do.  Why can't you simply  run `./configure --prefix /tmp/desired/location`?

Comment: That's a valid question. I cannot to set `--prefix` to that location for various reasons, including that my build location is different from my application's "install" location. I simply want to pass the appropriate linker flag while using `configure`.

Comment: Your scenario is still not clear to me.  Could you explain how the standard `./configure --prefix /somewhere && make && make install` is wrong for your setup? Why would your build location matter? (You should use an absolute prefix, of course.) Are you trying to link to `libglflags` without installing it?  (In that case you should use `libtool` to link your application with `libflag.la` and let libtool do its magic to link with a non-installed library.)   Do you want to install the library to a temporary location before it is copied to its final location? (It's a job for the DESTDIR variable.)

Comment: The Apple folks recommend using ***`-headerpad_max_install_names`*** to compile and link. Then, when you ***`make install`***, you use ***`install_name_tool`*** to update the record so its points to the fully qualified pathname (i.e., `/usr/local/lib/libfoo.dylib`). Nick X basically answered the same, but he did not mention the Apple's recommendation or ***`-headerpad_max_install_names`***.

Answer (score 8):

Generally, passing linker arguments through g++ must be prefaced with -Wl and spaces must be replaced with commas. So, if you want to pass "-install_name /tmp/temp.dylib" to the linker you will need to call this:

```
g++ -Wl,-install_name,/tmp/temp.dylib ...
```

Answer (score 5):

one possible approach would be editing the config.status manually. but before I try to do that, `install_name_tool -id` saved my life.