# Defining Framework path relative to executable in gnu/clang compiler on mac

Tags: c++, macos, clang, sdl

I'm trying to compile a simple c++ test program with the [SDL2 Framework](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) on mac 10.9.5 with clang++ 5.1.

I'm trying to understand how to compile with frameworks manually in gnu/clang, so please refrain from answers that would require Xcode.

## Project layout

```
Project/
|
|-- Output/
|   |-- <Unix Executable File>
|   |-- SDL2.framework
|
|-- Source/
|   |-- main.cpp
|
|-- Frameworks/
|   |-- SDL2.framework
```

Where main.cpp simply contains:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int, char**) {
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
    std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << "SDL LOADED CORRECTLY!" << std::endl;
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

And SDL2.framework is from the [2.0.3 Mac Development Library](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php).

## Compiling

I can successfully compile and link with clang:

```
clang++ -framework SDL2 -FFrameworks Source/main.cpp -o Output/main_test
```

Using the `-F` preprocessor flag to manually add the `Frameworks` directory to the search path for Framework include files.

## Running

The resulting executable runs correctly if `SDL2.framework` exists in the Global frameworks directory, `/Library/Frameworks/`:

```
$ sudo cp -R Frameworks/SDL2.framework/ /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/
$ ./Output/main_test
SDL LOADED CORRECTLY!
```

However I would prefer it if the executable used the `SDL2.framework` in the Output directory instead of requiring one in the Global frameworks directory.

But without the global framework the executable no longer runs:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/
$ sudo cp -R Frameworks/SDL2.framework/ Output/SDL2.framework/
$ ./Output/main_test
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
  Referenced from: /Users/Jo/Desktop/Temp_Project/./Output/main_test
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

## Question

Is `@rpath` the path from where the executable is being run? In which case, why is it not able to find it? As far as I can tell the files needed are in the correct location:

```
$ ls -l Output/ 
total 32
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 Jo  staff    204 Mar 15  2014 SDL2.framework
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Jo  staff  15252 Jun 24 17:35 main_test

$ ls -l Output/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/
total 3448
drwxr-xr-x@ 56 Jo  staff     1904 Mar 15  2014 Headers
drwxr-xr-x@  3 Jo  staff      102 Mar 15  2014 Resources
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Jo  staff  1762208 Mar 15  2014 SDL2
drwxr-xr-x@  3 Jo  staff      102 Mar 15  2014 _CodeSignature
```

With the following `otool` Library output:

```
otool -L Output/main_test 
Output/main_test:
    @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2 (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 3.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

## TL;DR

Is there a step that I am missing when compiling that would enable the executable to use for the Framework in a location relative to it instead of an absolute global one?

It seems like [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506450/clang-change-dependent-shared-library-install-name-at-link-time) could be related but as of this post it has yet to be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while but I now finally understand how to use `@rpath`.

@rpath on a library/framework means that the executable can provide a path, which we can set using `-rpath`, and we can set it in terms of `@executable_path`.

In this case, when compiling my `main_test` executable I would need to do the following:

```
clang++ -framework SDL2 -F ./Frameworks Source/main.cpp -o ./Output/main_test -rpath @executable_path/
```

Then when running `main_test`, because `@rpath` is going to be the path to the executable (`@executable_path`), the library will load correctly from its relative location.