# Mac OS High Sierra Invalid Mex file and Symbol not found errors

Tags: matlab, file, mex, dylib

While running a Matlab code I get this error

> ```
> Invalid MEX-file '/Users/ericelharar/Documents/MATLAB/Eric_Pedro/BM3D/bm3d_thr.mexmaci64':
>    dlopen(/Users/ericelharar/Documents/MATLAB/Eric_Pedro/BM3D/bm3d_thr.mexmaci64, 6):
>    Symbol not found: _mxCreateNumericArray_700
>    Referenced from: /Users/ericelharar/Documents/MATLAB/Eric_Pedro/BM3D/bm3d_thr.mexmaci64
>    Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
> in /Users/ericelharar/Documents/MATLAB/Eric_Pedro/BM3D/bm3d_thr.mexmaci64.
> ```

Tried looking for `libSystem.B.dylib` with no success

tried `otool -L /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`
got error message

> ```
> '/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib': No such file or directory
> ```

I'm using Mac OS  High Sierra 10.13.4 (17E199), Xcode 9.3 and Matlab 2018a

Comment: Did you compile the MEX-file yourself? If it was copied over from a different computer you might have to recompile it to get it to work. The function `_mxCreateNumericArray_700` that it's looking for is in one of MATLAB's libraries. Also, MATLAB 2018a introduced some breaking changes in how MEX-files are compiled.

Comment: Hi, the BM3D code was downloaded from http://www.cs.tut.fi/~foi/GCF-BM3D/ (the file is http://www.cs.tut.fi/~foi/GCF-BM3D/BM3D.zip

Comment: trying to solve the problem for 3 weeks by now, really appreciate your trying to help

Comment: Those come without the sources, so you cannot recompile them. See if one of these answers help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48177962/7328782 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/48473295/7328782 -- If not, contact the authors of the package see if they're willing to update it for newer OS and MATLAB version.

Comment: Thank you for your time, appreciate your reply. tried that before with no help. if you have another idea please let me know. starting to give up.....